# PDF Document looks fine, but rotation is incorrect -

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, acrobat

I have some PDF documents on my server and I'm appending them together with iTextSharp. ALl documents appear normal when I open them up, however there is one document in particular that seems to have a rotation value that is incorrect. It looks like a normal letter-sized document in portrait mode. When I run this VB.NET code to loop through the pages

Dim rotation as integer = reader2.GetPageRotation(X)

All values are coming back as "270". What the heck? This document is obviously not rotated 270 degrees. When I open it with Acrobat or the mozilla PDF.js viewer, everything is fine. All other documents are coming back fine (rotation = 0) except for this one.

Does anyone know what could have caused this? I didn't create the PDF, it was scanned and from an outside source so my guess is someone's scanner or scanning software is out of wack and saving incorrect rotation values.

Is there an easy way to correct this without ITextSharp, such as Adobe Professional? I've got adobe professional and it does show a lot of metadata about the PDF such as different security fields (allow editing, etc), but since iTextSharp can pull this "rotation" field, I assume that this rotation field is a metadata field that can be edited with some sort of program like Nitro/Acrobat/et, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Comment: if it started as a "landscape" page, rotated 270 degrees will make it "portrait" as you'd be rotating it (3 * 90). To know the true orientation of a page, I suggest you use `Rectangle currentPageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);` and then evaluate the size of `currentPageRectangle` to know if you are dealing with a Landscape(x > y) or Portrait (x < y) page. Then you can take corrective actions when you put the page in your new PDF file. A portrait page showing a 270 degree rotation is pretty common in my world.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes as soon as I can. For now I basically just have it completely ignore the rotation. I'm appending pages from different docs in my app and technically they should all be portrait. For now I'm just going to append them without checking rotation, If the user uploads something in landscape mode for now it will be their problem since they didn't read the instructions ;) But for now this method works. I DO want to be diligent through so I will give your method a try.